# How do I use an asp-action in a Asp.Net Core DevExtreme DataGrid column in a Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, devextreme

I have an Asp.NetCore web app built using EFC written in C#. The webpages are built using Razor. I am attempting to use a DevExpress DevExtreme DataGrid in a page.

**Here is my model class definition:**

```
public class Owner
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my page definition:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Owner>
@{ Layout = "_DevExtremeLayout"; ViewBag.Title = "All Owners";}

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<SmartTracPoc.Models.Owner>()
    .DataSource(Model)
    .RemoteOperations(true)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.AddFor(m => m.FirstName);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.LastName);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.PhoneNumber);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.OwnerId).CellTemplate(@<text><form asp-action="DeleteOwner" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" value="m => m.OwnerId" name="OwnerId" />
                    <input type="image" src="/icon/close.png" />
                </form>
                </text>);       
    })
)
```

**Here is the associated code snippet from the controller file:**

```
public class OwnerController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteOwner(Guid ownerId)
    {
        try
        {
            var requestString = SmartTrocPocServerAddress + $"Owners/{ownerId.ToString()}";
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync(requestString);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OwnerController::DeleteOwner() - exception occured");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I'd like to use an asp-action in a column definition to fire the associated Delete method in my controller. The DeleteOwner() method in the controller is successfully getting fired, but my id parameter is 0.

**Previous to using the DevExtreme DataGrid, the following page definition snippet worked correctly:**

```
@foreach (var r in Model)
{
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <form asp-action="DeleteOwner" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="@r.OwnerId" name="OwnerId" />
        <input type="image" src="/icon/close.png" />
     </form>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
}
```

How do I bind the OwnerId to the  on the call to my controller method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%- data.OwnerId %>" name="OwnerId" />
```